# Xcode Error with Linking View Controllers with UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have made an a `Tabbed Bar` Application in Xcode and the First Tab is Decors. I asked a previous question on integrating a XIB Project into a StoryBoard Tabbed Project.

I have Been Successfully in the integration of this, And it works but when I push on one of the Deocrs, Or Table Cells I get the following Error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "SelectedCellViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.`

If I put the Original Alert into my project The cell linking starts to work again.

Below are pics, links and code to my project, So you can see how it works

[StoryBoard Project](http://studio.netnrg.co.za/dev/rnd/blake.loizides/xcode/storyboard.zip)

[XIB Project](http://studio.netnrg.co.za/dev/rnd/blake.loizides/xcode/xib.zip)

[image]

[image]

**DecorsViewController_iPhone.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DecorsViewController_iPhone : UIViewController

{
IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewDecors;
NSArray *sitesArray;
NSArray *imagesArray;
}


@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableViewDecors;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *sitesArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *imagesArray;


@end
```

**DecorsViewController_iPhone.m**

```
 #import "DecorsViewController_iPhone.h"
 #import "SelectedCellViewController.h"

@interface DecorsViewController_iPhone ()

@end

@implementation DecorsViewController_iPhone

@synthesize tableViewDecors;
@synthesize sitesArray;
@synthesize imagesArray;

 #pragma mark - View lifecycle

 // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  - (void)viewDidLoad {

// Load up the sitesArray with a dummy array : sites
NSArray *sites = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f", @"g", @"h", nil];
self.sitesArray = sites;
//[sites release];

UIImage *active = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];
UIImage *ae = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];
UIImage *audio = [UIImage imageNamed:@"c.png"];
UIImage *mobile = [UIImage imageNamed:@"d.png"];
UIImage *net = [UIImage imageNamed:@"e.png"];
UIImage *photo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"f.png"];
UIImage *psd = [UIImage imageNamed:@"g.png"];
UIImage *vector = [UIImage imageNamed:@"h.png"];

NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: active, ae, audio, mobile, net, photo, psd, vector, nil];
self.imagesArray = images;
//[images release];

[super viewDidLoad];
}


#pragma mark - Table View datasource methods

// Required Methods

// Return the number of rows in a section
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [sitesArray count];
}

// Returns cell to render for each row
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure cell

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

// Sets the text for the cell
//cell.textLabel.text = [sitesArray objectAtIndex:row];

// Sets the imageview for the cell
cell.imageView.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:row];

// Sets the accessory for the cell
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

// Sets the detailtext for the cell (subtitle)
//cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is row: %i", row + 1];

return cell;
 }

// Optional

// Returns the number of section in a table view
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View delegate methods

// Return the height for each cell
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 78;
}

// Sets the title for header in the tableview
-(NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section     {
return @"Decors";
 }

// Sets the title for footer
-(NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section     {
return @"Decors";
}

// Sets the indentation for rows
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 0;
}


// Method that gets called from the "Done" button (From the @selector in the line - [viewControllerToShow.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissView)] autorelease]];)
- (void)dismissView {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

// This method is run when the user taps the row in the tableview
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

SelectedCellViewController *viewControllerToShow = [[SelectedCellViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectedCellViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[viewControllerToShow setLabelText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You selected cell: %d - %@", indexPath.row, [sitesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
[viewControllerToShow setImage:(UIImage *)[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

[viewControllerToShow setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[viewControllerToShow setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[viewControllerToShow.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissView)]];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewControllerToShow];
viewControllerToShow = nil;

    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:NULL];
navController = nil;

    //  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tapped row!"
//                                            message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You tapped: %@", [sitesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
//                                            delegate:nil
//                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes, I did!"
//                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
//  [alert show];
//  [alert release];

}

#pragma mark - Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
NSLog(@"Memory Warning!");
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
self.sitesArray = nil;
self.imagesArray = nil;
[super viewDidUnload];
 }


 //- (void)dealloc {
 //[sitesArray release];
//[imagesArray release];
//  [super dealloc];
//}

@end
```

**SelectedCellViewController.h**

```
@interface SelectedCellViewController : UIViewController {
NSString *labelText;
UIImage *image;

IBOutlet UILabel *label;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *labelText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;

@end
```

**viewControllerToShow.m**

```
#import "SelectedCellViewController.h"

@implementation SelectedCellViewController

@synthesize labelText;
@synthesize image;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[label setText:self.labelText];
[imageView setImage:self.image];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
self.labelText = nil;
self.image = nil;
//[label release];
// [imageView release];
[super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

 @end
```

Comment: I Figured it out. I can actually use an External XIB File and not include it with my storyboard file to work. Very Cool. I'm Learning quickly:)Thanks for all the advice everybody that helped.

Answer (score 0):

check the class inherited by the "The controller to be shown on click".XIB in the identity inspector .It seems you have not set the class for the "to be shown" XIB and the view outlet of the same XIB.